# validate parent's key with Child's value in nested json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

can i get some advice on the json parsing using Javascript:

The json format in the above example is a nested json, trying to validate parent's key with Child's value...

say we have 100 students, each student's data looks like this:

```
{
  "studentName": "good student",
  "age": "18",
  "address": "street 123",
  "courses":   {
    "math":     {
      "description": "how to calculate",
      "enrollment": "enrolled",
      "status": {"result": "OK"}
    },
    "English":     {
      "description": "abc",
      "enrollment": "not-enrolled",
      "status": {"result": "OK"}
    }
  }
}
```

The goal of the validation is to make sure each student's match class is "enrolled"
, as it is a required class. The English class can be "enrolled" or "not-enrolled", as English class is optional.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided a student object, you simply need to check if the course exists with an enrolled status in the student's courses object.

```js
var student = { 
  "studentName": "good student",
  "age": "18",
  "address": "street 123",
  "courses": { 
    "Math": { 
      "description": "how to calculate", 
      "enrollment": "enrolled", 
      "status": {"result": "OK"} 
    }, 
    "English": { 
      "description": "abc", 
      "enrollment": "not-enrolled", 
      "status": {"result": "OK"} 
    } 
  } 
};

function isStudentEnrolledInCourse(student, course) {
  var courses = student.courses;
  var courseObj = courses[course];
  if (typeof courseObj === 'undefined' ||courseObj.enrollment !== 'enrolled') {
    return false;  
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(isStudentEnrolledInCourse(student, 'Math'));
```

Given a list of 100 students, you could simply iterate over the list and call the `isStudentEnrolledInCourse` function on each object. Also, if you have a JSON string instead of a javascript object, don't forget to parse it with `JSON.parse(jsonString)`.